# jQuery Add New Field

Tags: jquery

So, what I'm trying to do here is onClick add another <li> that was exactly like the one above it. I have created a for loop in PHP to create the proper fields inside of this <li>.

The problem that I am running in to: When you click the .repatable-add button I get the "before replace" alert twice and the "after replace" alert does not fire at all. **And ideas?**

```
jQuery('.repeatable-add').click(function() { 
    field = jQuery(this).siblings('ul.image-details').find('li:last').clone(true);  
    fieldLocation = jQuery(this).siblings('ul.image-details').find('li:last');  
    jQuery('input', field).val('').attr('name', function(index, name) {
            alert(name +' before replace');
            return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {  
            return Number(n) + 1;  
            alert(name +' after replace');
        });  
    })  
    field.insertAfter(fieldLocation, jQuery(this).siblings('ul.image-details').find('li:last'))  
    return false;  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this answer to this somewhere else, don't konw what happened.

it's because you're trying to do the alert after a return, and so it won't fire.

I'm not sure of what you're trying to do with the input thing, but here's a solution I came up with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.repeatable-add').click(function(){
            var copyThis = jQuery(".image-details").find("li:last").attr('outerHTML');
            jQuery(".image-details").append(copyThis);
            var name = jQuery("input").attr("name");
            var count = name.replace(/\D+/, '');
            var newCount = count++;
            jQuery("input").attr("name",name.replace(newCount.toString(),count.toString()));
        return false;  
    });  
});
</script>

<ul class="image-details">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<input name="ithas1" />
<button class='repeatable-add'>button</button>
```